# BeautifulSoup not targeting anything after specifying the element and classname

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, lxml

I'm trying to scrape this website https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Korean_drama. Specifically the list of highest rated Korean dramas in cable television. This is what inspect element looks like [image]

This is my code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Korean_drama'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
kdramas = soup.find_all(
    'table', class_="wikitable sortable jquery-tablesorter")
print(kdramas)
for kdrama in kdramas:
    print(kdrama.text)
```

This is what happens when I run my code

```
admins-MBP:~ admin$ python3 kdramas.py
[]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the `jquery-tablesorter` class may be added dynamically, which is why it isn't getting read by BeautifulSoup.

My recommendation would be to go for that `h3` tag that introduces the table, then dig into the first table object in the DOM after that.

Something like:

```
# h3 tag name is actually in a <span> inside the h3 element
table_lead_in = soup.find('span', id="List_of_highest-rated_Korean_dramas_in_public_broadcast")

for drama_table in table_lead_in.find_next('tbody'):
    for tr in drama_table.find_all_next('tr'):
        rank = tr.find('td').text
        title = tr.find('a').text
        print(f"Title: {title} ** Rank: {rank}")
```

Output:

```
Title: You and I ** Rank: 1
Title: First Love ** Rank: 2
Title: What Is Love ** Rank: 3
Title: Sandglass ** Rank: 4
Title: Hur Jun ** Rank: 5
Title: A Sunny Place of the Young ** Rank: 6
Title: Sons and Daughters ** Rank: 7
```

(Note: There are a few lazy assumptions baked into the `find()` calls, but for demonstration purposes this should suffice.)

Answer (score 0):

I see nothing wrong with the specified code.

My recommendation is to try the other tags higher up in the hierarchy and observe the output. Different sites have different tags and classes so there is no one fix all solution. Maybe try div tags higher up in the hierarchy first.

Comment: I think this is better suited as a comment - [When should I answer or comment?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297066/meta-meta-stack-overflow-when-should-i-answer-or-comment)

Answer (score 0):

The class `wikitable sortable jquery-tablesorter` is sometimes named as `wikitable sortable`.
You can use a CSS selector to select the class that starts with `wikitable sortable`, which will work in either case:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Korean_drama'

response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
kdramas = soup.select_one('table[class^="wikitable sortable"]:nth-of-type(2)')

for row in kdramas.select('tr'):
    data = [td.get_text(strip=True) for td in row.select('td')]
    print(' '.join('{: <30}'.format(d) for d in data))
```